# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '***.indices' doesn't exist laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have table indexpage but still have this error! this is my code:

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('index', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('about');
            $table->string('video');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

model:

```
class Index extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'about' ,'video'
    ];
}
```

where indices come from?

Comment: plz post your model, do u call it by model?

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: I have post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By convention, the "snake case", **plural name of the class** will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified.

In your Index Model, you need to explicitly specified the table name

```php
class Index extends Models {
    protected $table = 'index';
    ...
}
```

Comment: @hadis u r welcome. plz accept the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`indices` is the plural form of 'index'. By default, laravel will look for a plural form of the model.For example `App\User` refers to `users` table. 
Thats the convention.

`'***.indices'` not found, but your schema class (migration) is creating a 'index' table.

Add the following in your model. Should work fine.

```
protected $table = 'index';
```